# "SKU value not supported"

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-notificationhub

I tried to make a notification hub for FCM app server.

so I followed the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started,

but when I tried to deploy it, there's error "SKU value not supported"

I'm using student license, is there any problem when I using this solution?

or is there some reason I cannot deploy it"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! Could you please check if your Azure account is active? Notification Hubs is offered in three tiers: free, basic, and standard. Check this article which shows you [how to change the pricing tier for an Azure Notification Hubs namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/change-pricing-tier).

For detailed information about tiers and pricing, see [Notification Hubs pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)